# MAC OSX User accept password but does not allow me to login?

Tags: osx-lion, user-accounts, keychain-access

I have deleted the login keychain in user ABC which is administrator user, i remember the password. I also have a CDF user on my mac which is also administrator.

When at login I give password to ABC user, it accepts then refresh the screen again for selection of users and giving password again. If I give password to any other user system login to that users.

Is there any way to Login the ABC user by making any change to keychain via CDF user.

Comment: Why don't you just delete the existing user with what access you have and create a new user?  Why was the keychain deleted?

Comment: I deleted keychain due to developer certificates issue. I can't delete the user as i have huge data associated with that.

Answer (score 0):

How did you delete the keychain of the user? If `/Users/*/Library/Keychains/login.keychain` exists, you could try deleting it in any case.

You could also try changing the password of the other account. Open the Users & Groups preference pane, click the lock icon, select the account, press the Reset Password... button, and enter a new password.

If `/etc/kcpassword` exists, you could also try deleting it. It is used to store the keychain password when automatic login is enabled.